# Cypress / JavaScript: assertion with an URL value that contains a specific word

Tags: css, cucumber, cypress, assertion, cypress-xpath

I'm trying to improve the following assertion:

```javascript
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')
  .should('have.css', 'background-image', 
    'url("https://assets.website.com/folder/house.jpg")'
  );
```

In the test I am verifying if that div has the CSS `background-image` property with that `url` value.

I want to convert this assertion to verifying that the div has the css `background-image` property with a value that contains "house.jpg" instead of the entire URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it with a simple string `include` check

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')
  .should('have.css', 'background-image')  // changes subject to css value
  .and('include', 'house.jpg')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a callback function with `.should()` for more complicated checking.

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')
  .should($el => {
    const backgroundImage = $el.css('background-image')
    expect(backgroundImage).to.include('house.jpg) // retries if expect() fails initially
  })
```

Depending on how it is applied (style sheets or SCSS), you may have to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the actual CSS value,

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')
  .should($el => {
    const backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle($el[0])['background-image']
    expect(backgroundImage).to.include('house.jpg)   
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to shorten the url assertion is a partial string check, since `house.js` is part of `url("https://assets.website.com/folder/house.jpg")`.

Cypress commands pass along a "subject" from one step to the next. So `cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')` passes the whole element to `.should()`.

You can change the subject from the element to it's `background-image` style value using the jQuery `css()` method.

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')  // yields the element
  .invoke('css', 'background-image')      // applies .css('background-image') to
                                          // the element and yields the string value
  .should('include', 'house.jpg')         // assert the value has "house.jpg"
```

Ref [.invoke()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple regex for assertion as well like this as mentioned in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Yields).

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@data-testid="column"]')
  .should('have.css', 'background-image')
  .and('match', /house.jpg/)
```